# Filter types in collection using FilterDefinition

Tags: c#, mongodb-.net-driver

The driver complains when I attempt to filter records by type/discriminator:

```
var types = new List<Type> { typeof (ConcreteClassA), typeof (ConcreteClassB) };
query &= Builders<AbstractClass>.Filter.Where (obj => types.Any (type => obj.GetType ().IsInstanceOfType (type)));
```

> value(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Type]) is not supported.

Even if I try to compare against one type I get an exception:

```
query &= Builders<AbstractClass>.Filter.Where (obj => obj.GetType ().IsInstanceOfType (typeof (ConcreteClassA));
```

I know in the 1.x driver I could use an `OfType<ConcreteClassA>()` solution. Is there any similar method when using a `FilterDefinition` ?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you to use `OfType` like below that will give you `FilterDefinition`:

```
var filterTypeA = Builders<AbstractClass>.Filter.OfType<ConcreteClassA>();
var filterTypeB = Builders<AbstractClass>.Filter.OfType<ConcreteClassB>();
var filter = Builders<AbstractClass>.Filter.Or(filterA, filterB);

var result = collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync().Result;
```

But you can also use `is` operator like below:

```
var filter = Builders<AbstractClass>.Filter
    .Where(w=> w is ConcreteClassA || w is ConcreteClassB);
```